# Setting div 100% of window without content overflowing

Tags: html, css, layout, height

I am trying to set up my page layout to take up 100% of the screen but am running into problems with content overflowing into the footer.

Here's the code for the first example:

**HTML**:

```
<div class="container page-container">
    <div class="page-leftSidebar">
        <div class="sidebar" role="complementary">
            <h4>Widget Title</h4>
                    </div>

        <main class="post-wrapper" role="main">
            <section class="entry-content">
                <p>This makes the entire page 100% height, but <code>.post-wrapper</code> is not for some reason.</p>
            </section>
        </main>
    </div>
</div>

<footer class="siteFooter">
    <p>Copyright 2015 Me.</p>
</footer>
```

**CSS:**

```
/* Generic */
html,
body { height: 100%; }

body {
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0;
}


/* Containers */
.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 90%;
}

.page-container { min-height: 100%; }


/* Page Content */
.post-wrapper {
    background-color: #fff;
    min-height: 100%;
}

/* This is the row that will hold our two columns (sidebar and content) */
.page-leftSidebar {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}

.page-leftSidebar:after {
    clear: both;
    content:" ";
    display: table;
}

.page-leftSidebar .sidebar { -webkit-background-clip: padding-box; }

@media (min-width: 60em) {
    /* Page container */
    .page-leftSidebar .post-wrapper {
        -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
        min-height: 100%;
    }

    /* Left Sidebar */
    .page-leftSidebar .sidebar {
        float: left;
        width: 19.25%;
    }

    /* Right Content */
    .page-leftSidebar .post-wrapper {
        float: left;
        margin-left: 2%;
        width: 78.75%;
    }
}


/* Site Footer */
.siteFooter {
    background-color: #2b303b;
    color: #555555;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    padding-top: 50px;
}


/* FULL PAGE HEIGHT */
.container { min-height: 100%; }

.post-wrapper,
.page-leftSidebar,
.sidebar {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}
```

I got things kind of working here, but my `.post-wrapper` container is still not 100% height: http://jsfiddle.net/1re4vLq4/10/

However, the above example *does* work if there is a lot of content on the page: http://jsfiddle.net/1re4vLq4/9/ (**Note:** that both this and the above example are using `min-height`)

Then I got the entire page (including `.post-wrapper`) to be 100% height by using `height` instead of `min-height`: http://jsfiddle.net/9m1krxuv/4/

**Changed CSS:**

```
.container { height: 100%; }

.post-wrapper,
.page-leftSidebar,
.sidebar {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}
```

However, the problem with this is when there is a lot of content on the page, it overflows onto the footer (you can see this by making the result pane in JSFiddle smaller): http://jsfiddle.net/1re4vLq4/8/ Which shouldn't be the case (nor do I want to hide the text using `overflow: hidden`).

Any suggestions or ideas on how to go about fixing this? I'm looking for the entire page to be at least 100% height, including `.post-wrapper` (which is the right column with a white background).

Comment: What would happen if jsfiddle went down? This question would be obsolete because you didn't post your code here. That means you can't help someone else with the same problem that you have out.

Comment: Fair enough, I have added code examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a "full-sized" container that you want to always match the height of the viewport - you're best not to add content that will *overflow* (go beyond) that div, as you're essentially defeating the purpose.

Short answer: Remove `height: 100%;` from your `.container` CSS rule.

I've created a basic Fiddle example combining full-viewport-height divs, and divs that just hold a lot of content.

HTML:

```
 <div class="full-div red height-full">
        <!-- Full sized div. Content should fit within the viewport -->
    </div>
    <div class="full-div blue">
        <div class="inner-div">
            <!-- Add long lorem ipsum here. -->
            <!-- Notice that the parent div does not contain the height-full class -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="full-div green height-full">
        <!-- This div will get "pushed down"only because the div above is NOT height 100% -->
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
html,body{ height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }

.full-div { overflow: auto; }

.height-full { height: 100%; }

.inner-div { width: 90%; background-color: white; margin: 0 auto; }
.inner-div span { text-align: center; }
```

DEMO here: http://jsfiddle.net/175mrgzt/

Ultimately, when you set a DIV to 100% - its expected to be 100% of the viewport (graphical viewing region of the browser). Once you add content that extends that you're essentially going *over* 100% - and in that case, you might as well remove the set height, and let HTML make the adjustments for you.